# Как не передавать выбранный параметр по умолчанию?

Tags: php, html

На страницу оформления заказа передаются выбранные параметры через выпадающий список таким вот образом:

```
<h6 style="margin-bottom:20px">Выбор страны</h6>
<select class="selectpicker" name="country" data-size="10" data-style="">
<option value="none">Не выбрано</option>
<option value="YE">Yemen</option>
<option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
<option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Далее идет огромная по размеру функция включающая в себя перевод на человеческий язык всех параметров калькулятора:

```
if (isset($_POST['country']))
{
        switch ($_POST['country']) {      
          case 'YE': $country = "Yemen"; break;
          case 'ZM': $country = "Zambia"; break;
          case 'ZW': $country = "Zimbabwe"; break;
          case 'none': $country = "Не выбрано"; break;
          default: $country = $_POST['country'];
        }
        $description .= "Страна: ".$country."<br/>";  
      }
```

Первый параметр из выпадающего списка по умолчанию "Не выбрано". Как сделать, чтобы только этот самый параметр не передавался на страницу оформления заказа?

Comment: Прочитал несколько раз - всё равно не понял

Comment: Вопрос поправил

Comment: не ясна фраза "чтобы только этот самый параметр не передавался на страницу оформления заказа?".  Что она значит? просто не обрабатывайте эту опцию и всё

Comment: Если не обрабатывать эту опцию, то добавится следующая. Это значит, что если по умолчанию выбрано "не выбрано", то опция ни несет никакой информации. Задайтесь вопросом, какой смысл выводить опцию "Страна: не выбрано". Никакого. А если этот выбор осуществлен, то он должен быть осмысленным. А если не осуществлен, то это значит неактуальная опция для заказчика

Comment: " Задайтесь вопросом, какой смысл выводить опцию "Страна: не выбрано". Никакого." --- ошибаетесь. В заказе должно быть всё указано, все пункты заказа..., Но если человек не захотел указывать и там логично указать что данные не были выбраны. Так же например по дефолту бывает выбрана опция "неизвестен"  ведь не на каждый товар (например при  продаже вещи на авито) пользователь знает или помнит например марку товара. Вы немного загнались и не тем.

Comment: ....А что значит "Если не обрабатывать эту опцию, то добавится следующая." ?? куда добавится? Где добавится? почему она должна добавиться?

Comment: Если так принципиально, то просто не добавляй обработку в case. А после `switch/case` напиши, если страна не равна `none` то только тогда к `description` конкатенировать `"Страна: ".$country."<br/>"` И всё

Comment: Если не выводить эту опцию, то выводится следующая. Ну вот, к примеру первый select "Не выбрано", а второй "Афганистан", это значит, что если убрать "Не выбрано", то будет выводиться Афганистан по умолчанию. "А после switch/case напиши, если страна не равна none то только тогда к description конкатенировать "Страна: ".$country."<br/>" И всё" Развернутый вариант можете показать?

Answer (score 0):

Решение. Нужно было добавить disabled и selected

```
         <h6 style="margin-bottom:20px">Выбор страны</h6>
<select class="selectpicker" name="country" data-size="10" data-style="">
<option value="none" disabled selected>Не выбрано</option>
<option value="YE">Yemen</option>
<option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
<option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А если пользователь выберет страну, но потом передумает и захочет перевыбрать на "не выбрано"? Или случайно рука соскользнёти надо будет обратно на дефолтный поставить?

Answer (score -2):

добавьте проверку значения перед отправкой:

```
if (document.querySelector('[name="country"]').value != "none")
{
    if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: В каких таких интересных вузах учат совмещать js и php?

Comment: не в курсе был,что это php. В вопросе не было указаний на это. В прочем, смысл тот же будет: нужно проверить значение перед отправкой. Как это сделать на php, наверное автор разберёться сам.